# Unique string to identify user file

Tags: language-agnostic, unique, filepath

We have a system that has many machines working together. At some point they need to create a image and upload it to a media server. This media server is just a web server providing static files. We dont want to display the incremental id of each image so we need to obfuscate the image name.

Because each machine has a unique user and we keep track only of the generated url we decided to use `HMAC-SHA256(secret, user_id)` to generate filenames for each image.

This results in images with this kind of names: `b3dbaea7adef41e8ecbeaa0cd8ec02d57f0334a6e003271d5e334ae2e46b4285.jpg`

Is not the most beautiful solution but it does works, for now.

Because some business changes now we need this image to be generated more frequent and we need to create folders for each user.

How can I keep the unique file path without it being so large and, at the same time, avoid collision between image names or between user folders

I want to avoid this kind of path: `b3dbaea7adef41e8ecbeaa0cd8ec02d57f0334a6e003271d5e334ae2e46b4285/b3dbaea7adef41e8ecbeaa0cd8ec02d57f0334a6e003271d5e334ae2e46b4285.jpg`

Comment: [Is obfuscating URLs really a good idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342048/when-is-it-ok-to-intentionally-obfuscate-urls)

Comment: Our system is not even close to snapchat, but consider this. If snapchat have unobfuscated urls pointing to images any user could just circle to all of them like so `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, ... This is what we don't want. Anyone can open any image, but they souldn't be able to circle to all existing images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5, as opposed to SHA256, will generate strings about half as long; if you used it for both the directory & file names, you'd have paths about as long as your current implementation.

Another thought: the character space used is much smaller (16 characters) than file and directory names would allow (either 36 or 62, depending on if you allow both cases or not, and that's sticking to alphanumerics), so you can map your hashes to smaller strings without raising the likelihood of collisions.

Comment: isn't MD5 easy to collide? We have to keep a minimum of 1 million images at all times and we dont keep track of which filenames can be reused, will MD5 be ok with that?

Comment: But now you only have to worry about collisions *between* folders and *within* folders.  Or, to put it another way: you now have to worry about *path* collisions, not *filename* collisions.